# BASH - Read - How to require [enter] to complete input? Example [y] + [enter]

Tags: bash, sh, prompt

I haven't been able to find an answer to this online, or in the `read` manual.

I have a simple Yes / No prompt, that accepts `y` or `n`.

I'm trying to have it require `enter` (specifically) to be pressed, after typing `y`, or `n`.

Example:

```
$ Do you want to continue?

_ y + enter

$ Continuing!
```

Below is the code I have currently:

```bash
while true; do
    read -n 1 -r -p "Continue (y/n):" yn

        case $yn in 
            [yY] ) 
                echo "Yes - Continuing..."
                break;;
            [nN] )
                echo "No - Exiting..."
                exit;;
            * ) 
                echo "Invalid response!";;
    esac
done
```

I've tried setting `-n 2` which "sort of" works, as it requires 2 keys to be pressed, however, if I type `y`, then change my mind and hit `backspace`, it will sill proceed and continue. Same thing if I "fat finger" things... like `bn` or `ty` will continue, since there's an `n` or a `y` in the response.

How can I require 2 keys to be pressed, one being `y` or `Y` and the `enter` key specifically, ignoring any other combination?

[Edit]

Setting `-n 2` and requiring `[yY]'' )` seems to work, but it still falls back to "Invalid Input" if I try `y` + `backspace`.

Not sure how I can ignore the `backspace` key being counted as an "input".

Comment: Perhaps you miss `case` instruction a line 4! `  case $yn in`...

Comment: To wait for *`Enter`* key, drop `-n` flag in `read` command. `read -rp "Continue (y/n): "`

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed that. It exists, but I cleaned up my code after pasting it here, and must have accidentally removed it.

Comment: You seem to be making unnecessary trouble for yourself.  Suppose you provide no `-n` option at all.  What harm results?

Comment: Also, dropping the `-n` flag does seem to help, but I can still get away with `yyyyyyyyyyy` + `enter`. Not sure this "really" matters, but I'm a perfectionist, and this to me, doesn't seem like a 100% solution. I was hoping to restrict this to a very specific `y` + `enter`, but I can live with this solution.

Comment: @JohnBollinger it's just my OCD. I expect things to work `exactly` and `specifically`, which is why I raised the question in the first place. I understand it's "more work than it's worth", but otherwise, to me, it just seems sloppy, and unfinished.

Comment: You may try to re-invent wheel by re-construct string and play with `read -rsn 1 oneKey` and a big loop containing all `case` ... This could become a very big job!

Comment: Yea, I'm starting to understand that this is probably a big waste of time, for an "extreme" circumstance, and I'm accepting that `y` (repeatable) + `enter` is "good enough" for my use case.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that simply changing `[yY]* )` "from the example linked" into `[yY] )` seems to restrict it to one single `y` character + `enter` allowing the user to continue.

Comment: What do you mean *changing* `[yY]* )` into `[yY] )`?  The latter is what was in the question from the beginning.  **Of course** the patterns for the responses you want to accept as valid should match only the patterns you want to accept as valid.  And note well that these are shell patterns (globs), not regular expressions.

Comment: I went back to the duplicate question posted, to explore it further, when I noticed that it "worked" but was accepting infinite `yyy` before continuing. That's when I removed the `*` which restricted the example to a single character `y` before allowing it to continue. Sometimes, I simply need to just write out, explain my issue, and have a bit of nudging guidance from others to find the answer that's right in front of my face the whole time.

Comment: Which character is generated by your backspace key? If you do `printf '<control-v><backspace>' | od -c` does it output `177` or `8` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

If, as is common on PC keyboards, when you hit the `Backspace` key on your keyboard it generates the `Del` character (ASCII dec 127, hex 177, Control-?), rather than the `backspace` character (ASCII 8, Control-H), then all you need is:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while true; do
    IFS= read -r -p 'Continue (y/n): ' yn

    case $yn in
        [yY] )
            echo 'Yes - Continuing...'
            break;;
        [nN] )
            echo 'No - Exiting...'
            exit;;
        * )
            echo 'Invalid response!';;
    esac

done
```

because the `read` will complete when you hit `Enter` to generate a newline, then the `case` will check for the 1 char before that newline being `y` or `n`.

Unless you put your terminal into "raw" mode your terminal buffers the keypresses until you hit `Enter` so the terminal, not your script, is what interprets that backspace keypress and deletes the preceding character from the input buffer before your script sees it. So if you type `n backspace y` your script will just read `y`, same as if you hadn't hit `n backspace` first. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/414171/133219 for more information.

Unfortunately the whole "Backspace" vs "Delete" area is a bit of a mess with Macs having a Delete key generating the Del character where the PC Backspace key is that generates Del character on some OSes and the BS character on others, and then Macs not having a Backspace key but instead requiring key combinations to generate BS, and PCs having a Delete key that generates something that isn't an ASCII character, etc. hence the "If your keyboard generates Del when Backspace is hit" caveat at the top of this answer.